# How to execute psexec command from python without specifying psexec exe location?

Tags: python, psexec

I have a python script from which i am executing a process on remote machine as follows:

```
sample= sp.Popen( ['c:/psexec/PsExec.exe','-i','-s','\\\\' + 'xyz','-u', 'sample','-p', 'xyz','C:/sample.bat'],stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

It executes well but what i want not to provide complete exe path as follows:

```
sample= sp.Popen( ['psexec','-i','-s','\\\\' + 'xyz','-u', 'sample','-p', 'xyz','C:/sample.bat'],stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

It does not work when i remove the complete psexec exe path. So, suggest what am i not doing right and how shall i execute python script using only psexec keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is fairly old, but it appears that psexec is not installed in the standard location, so it is likely that the location of the psexec binary is not in your systems's PATH environment variable.  Add `c:\psexec` to the PATH env var on the local machine, start a new command prompt, and this should work.